# How to get all filenames in a directory or folder using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to get all filenames in a directory or folder using jQuery and append to the redirected URL

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  GetDirectoryFiles();
});

function GetDirectoryFiles() { //function Definition for Get All FileNames Of Directory
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:55304/TestViewsGoogleImgChanged/",
    contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: null,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      var pagedata = $.parseHTML(data);
      var tabledata = $.parseHTML(pagedata[9].innerHTML);
      for (var i = 0; tabledata.length / 2; i++) {
        if (tabledata[i].textContent.indexOf('.cshtml') > 0) {
          window.open('http://123.com/' + tabledata[i].textContent.split(".cshtml")[0], '_blank')
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus + '-----' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to get the files on the server, then you need a server side language, such as ASP or PHP, not JS.

Comment: Basically it's a concept of getting thousands of filename from Folder at server or local using DOM. that u can acces from this certain code.

Comment: It's not possible to get access to client side files due to security restrictions. As I mentioned before, if you want to get them from the server you'll need a server side language

Answer (score -1):

Answer in the question itself.Firstly we will have to host our directory using FTP on specific location or on local system directly access through localhost which is mentioned in my solution Below Mention code is able to rectify the task discussed in the Question Posted.

According to requirement we can get the all the filenames and redirected to url(Filenames are appended to that URL) in new tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  GetDirectoryFiles();
});

function GetDirectoryFiles() { //function Definition for Get All FileNames Of Directory
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:55304/TestViewsGoogleImgChanged/",
    contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
    data: null,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      var pagedata = $.parseHTML(data);
      var tabledata = $.parseHTML(pagedata[9].innerHTML);
      for (var i = 0; tabledata.length / 2; i++) {
        if (tabledata[i].textContent.indexOf('.cshtml') > 0) {
          window.open('http://123.com/' + tabledata[i].textContent.split(".cshtml")[0], '_blank')
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus + '-----' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: 1) `async: false` is *really* bad practice. You should remove it. 2) This doesn't actually show *how* you get the folders which is the point of the question. All you do show is making an AJAX request, then looping through the result

Comment: Also the code here is ***identical*** to the question.

Comment: Act "async: false" it is requirement specific in my case it was required. and u can access the any Directory's content using Document object Model which is rendered view or browser view. and also as far as concern      
  "how you get the folders which is the point of the question"

Comment: You should change the requirements then, because there is no good reason to use `async: false`. It's a strong sign of bad architecture design/code smell. Your second sentence makes no sense I'm afraid.

Comment: As far as concern      
  "how you get the folders which is the point of the question" First u will have to host files on server using FTP then only u will be able to see it's DOM and consequently access using ajax and u can check from inspect element or F12

Comment: That's exactly my point. The part of your question that solves the problem is the code running under `http://localhost:55304/TestViewsGoogleImgChanged/` - and that's what you did not show. jQuery is irrelevant to that.

Comment: Agreed with u,and also i am edited for the Post "async:false" because it is somewhere misguided to coders